# Django - Creating a new user model extending an already extended user model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am starting a new project and I created my user model extending the `AbstractBaseUser`, like below:

```
class NewUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField( unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    ...
```

I am wondering whether it is possible and makes sense to create my user (e.g. Teacher)
by extending `NewUser`, and adding all of the Teacher profile info.
That would be something like:

```
class Teacher(NewUser):

    role = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date_of_birth = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    ...
```

Would this be good practice and would it allow me to use the built-in authentication methods with DRS?

And would this give more flexibility if then I want to enable other users (e.g. Students) to also register an account and log-in?

Or would it make more sense to just use `NewUser` directly?

Would Really appreciate some advice/ insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest using `OneToOneField` like this:

```py
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(NewUser, related_name='teacher')
    # Other fields that related to Teacher

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(NewUser, related_name='student')
    # Other fields that related to Student
```

So, `NewUser` model will be responsible only for the `login`, `signup`, and `permissions`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @MohamedHamza !
In your example, in the OneToOneField, sould I use User 
```OneToOneField(User, related_name='teacher')``` or NewUser ```OneToOneField(NewUser, related_name='teacher')``` ?
I'm not sure what the implication is

Comment: This is a mistake, I'll update it now!

Comment: HI @Mohamed Hamza , when I tried to implement this method. When I create the serialiazer for this method I recieve the error:

 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'email'

How should I build the user serializer?

Comment: Add the rest of your `NewUser` model, please!